Azure devops Pipeline Error Job Condition
I have a job that runs a matrix, then a cleanup job. If either of these fail or are cancelled, then I need a recovery job to run. I have seen a problem where one of the matrix jobs succeeds but the other agent gets rebooted (agent lost connection). The cleanup runs (always()), but the Error handler doesn't as the condition is neither failed nor cancelled. What am I doing wrong here?
- job: GetFiles
  strategy:
    matrix:
      AF0:
        MacId: 0
      AF1:
        MacId: 1
  steps:

- job: Cleanup
  dependsOn: GetFiles
  condition: always()
  steps:
  - powershell: |
    displayName: "Dismount"
    errorActionPreference: continue
    failOnStderr: false
    ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false

- job: ErrorControl
  dependsOn:
  - GetFiles
  - Cleanup
  condition: or(failed(), canceled())
  steps:


I can reproduce the similar issue when the previous job is skipped or notRun state.
For example:

The cause of the issue is that the previous jobs are not marked as failed or canceled. So it doesn't meet the condition in the ErrorControl job.
Based on your requirement, you need to run the ErrorControl job when the previous jobs are not completely success.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the following condition:
condition: or(ne(dependencies.GetFiles.result,'Succeeded'), ne(dependencies.Cleanup.result,'Succeeded'))

YAML sample:
jobs: 
- job: GetFiles
  strategy:
    matrix:
      AF0:
        MacId: 0
      AF1:
        MacId: 1
  steps:

- job: Cleanup
  dependsOn: GetFiles
  condition: always()
  steps:
  - powershell: |
    displayName: "Dismount"
    errorActionPreference: continue
    failOnStderr: false
    ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false

- job: ErrorControl
  dependsOn:
  - GetFiles
  - Cleanup
  condition: or(ne(dependencies.GetFiles.result,'Succeeded'), ne(dependencies.Cleanup.result,'Succeeded'))
  steps:

In this case, it will skip the last job only if all previous jobs succeeded. Otherwise it will execute the last stage.
Result:

